# Element not rendered below the fold

Tags: html, css, fold

I have a vertical navigation bar, which is supposed to go the entire height of the page. On small pages with no scroll it does, but once I scroll down I can see that the bar is ending right above the fold, and does not continue after scrolling. The CSS is:

```
.top-bar {
    width: 80px;
    min-width: 0;
    background: url(../img/grad-overlay-hz.png) #292929;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #515151;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: So is the bar supposed to be the height of the entire page (event the below the fold area) or just the browser window?

Comment: The entire height of the page, being the height of the window is the problem ;).

Comment: What does the html look like where the navigation is sitting? Have you tried setting min-height to 100% for the body and html tag as well?

Comment: Yes, I set the html and body to min-height 100. The navigation is a list wrapped in a div .top-bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the position: fixed property. This will hold the navigation bar always in the viewport.

```
.top-bar {
    width: 80px;
    min-width: 0;
    background-color: #292929;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #515151;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}​
```

Comment: That works for me, but the navigation icons are quite big, and the height of the entire bar is almost 800px, so people on smaller screens or on tablets/cellphones will never see all the navigation elements.

Comment: That is correct. Also position: fixed doesn't work that well on mobile devices. So I think you better not use it.

The cut off effect is well know but I don't remember the fix right now. Here is an explanation that you might want to read: http://delvauxkoen.blogspot.com/2010/01/common-css-bug-with-viewport-scrolling.html

Comment: You could try adjusting the content size using media queries while keeping it fixed.